# SQL Server: Parent id with the least number of children

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I have two tables `Client` and `Instructor`.

Client table :

```
id_client|name_client|FK_instructor
---------+-----------+------------
    1    | Clinton   |    2
    2    | Gates`    |    1
    3    | Bush      |    1
    4    | Clinton   |    2
    5    | Obama     |    1
    6    | Jack      |    3
```

Instructor table :

```
id_instructor|name_instructor
-------------+---------------
      1      |    Sara
      2      |    Sam            
      3      |    Dean
      4      |    Julie
      5      |    Jake
```

I want to select the 3 instructors who have the least number of clients associated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a group by with a join, an order by and a limit.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you mentioned you're using SQL Server, in addition to the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` you need a `TOP(3)` on your `SELECT`.

```
SELECT   TOP(3) i.id_instructor, i.name_instructor
FROM     Instructor i
JOIN     Client c ON c.FK_instructor = i.id_instructor
GROUP BY i.id_instructor, i.name_instructor
ORDER BY COUNT(*) --Implicitly ascending
```

Note that I added the instructor id to the group by compared to the other answer in case more than one instructor has the same name.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with **Netezza**, you could try:

```
SELECT name_instructor, COUNT(id_client)
FROM instructor_table
    JOIN client_table on instructor_table.id_instructor = client_table.FK_instructor
GROUP BY name_instructor
ORDER BY COUNT(id_client) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

There is great documentation for Netezza here: 
http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_sql_grammar.html

There are also SQL tutorials here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: This returns the instructors with the _highest_ number of clients, not with the _least_ number of clients (and you should mention for which DBMS this is, `LIMIT` is non-standard SQL)

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. You may want to add that this solution is for MySQL. This will not run if the db is SQLServer. Also `DESC` is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed I'm using SQL Server and the LIMIT is not working. and this Query gave me a list of instructors with the number of clients they have, but I want the result to be just the 3 names of instructors who have the least number of clients. Like if we have 10 instructors and everyone of them has some number of clients, I want just the 3 of them who have the least number of clients.